# Graphics.DrawLine isn't working as expected at high zoom level

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm writing a program which allow loading and displaying geometry. Recently, I added the zoom function. Everything works fine at low zoom level but when the zoom level increases (to about 10,000) the lines start to disappear. In some other cases, lines are very thick at one end and are very thin at the other end. The code I used to draw lines is as follow:

```
float edgeWidth = (float)(2/ scale);
Matrix tranf = new Matrix();
tranf.Scale((float)scale, (float)scale);
tranf.Translate(-offSet.X, -offSet.Y);
Graphics grp = displayArea.CreateGraphics();
grp.Transform = tranf;
grp.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, edgeWidth);
grp.DrawLine(pen, (float)(tempShape.subPoly[i][j].X), (float)(tempShape.subPoly[i][j].Y),
                        (float)(tempShape.subPoly[i][(j + 1) % tempShape.subPoly[i].Count].X), (float)(tempShape.subPoly[i][(j + 1) % tempShape.subPoly[i].Count].Y))
```

Comment: I believe the answer is yes :). Most likely you are also getting a lot of overflow exceptions /truncation of values when PointF internally converted to integers.

Comment: I use some data structures provided by my customer which use double. How can I avoid this problem without changing the provided data structures.